# Alias email trouble

Tags: web-services

I have a domain name that is regsitered for me
but my registerer had locked it and I am unable to reach it now

I happen to have the EPP code for this domain
and I really need to move this domain to my server
or just create an alias email account to use right now

do you happen to know what is the solution for me to create an email account using 
my EPP code .

Best Regards

Comment: Step 1: ask this on serverfault.com;  Step 2: contact the registrar and get control of your domain back.

Answer (score 0):

The EPP code will only allow you to transfer the domain to a new registrar. Once this is done you will be able to delegate it to your email hosts name servers or update the MX records to point to theirs.